# SSMS Template Browser Add-In development

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Okay, I’m trying to do something that I just can’t seem to get accomplished and I haven’t found anything online to address this request.

In the “Template Browser” I want to add another category of templates to keep the various templates separate. Looking at the template browser, there are two icons in the “header”. One icon is for the “SQL Server Templates” and the other is for the “Analysis Services Templates”. (See icons in red circle in the image below.)

I want to add a third icon (or more) to the header along with the “SQL Server Templates” icon and “Analysis Services Templates” icon.

Does anybody know if this is possible, and if so, how do you do it?  I'm a full-stack developer / DBA / BI and would like to build / modify this on my own as opposed to just installing a third party solution.

I have SQL Server 2012 with an instance of SSMS 2012 and an instance of SSMS 2018.

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  Your question is definitely on-topic for our site, and hopefully someone can help you out.

Comment: As another full-stack developer, the only information I can add (and hope helps) is that SSMS actually uses PowerShell to query the the list of entities it displays in the browsers.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that. I was wondering how the template browser was “auto” populated with the default generic templates. I tried deleting them from their folder, but every time I open SSMS in repopulates the folder and template browser. When I figure this out, I will definitely post my findings here.

Answer (score 1):

That would likely fall into the realm of SSMS Add-In Development.  Having said that, I'm not *certain* you can add a button to the Template Browser, even then.

Microsoft has a GitHub repo with a sample SSMS Add-In [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ssms-visualstudio-addin/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m just so close, but still can’t get this to work. I saw the link you sent, and will try from that angle. 
I was trying to edit the files manually but have had no luck so far. The “SQLWorkbenchProjectitems.vsdir” file seems to hold the reference list for the icons on the template browser. I tried adding another item to the list with no avail. 
I also tried editing the “UserSettings.xml” file that calls out the items in the list for each icon in the header. Still, no luck there. 
Obviously I’m missing another reference that needs to be modified. 
Thanks